# laravel edit form checkbox values old input

Tags: php, laravel

How do you use old('') for checkbox values. The problem with the code below is that it always is true and checked because of $baby_registry->reminder_email is true. So when you post the form without the checkbox being checked how do you test it in code if it's not there in the post request

```
@php
    $reminder_email = old('reminder_email', $baby_registry->reminder_email);
@endphp

<input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" {{ $reminder_email ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

I ended up having to do this for the code

```
@if($errors->any() && old('reminder_email') == 'on')
    <input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" checked>
@elseif($errors->any() && !old('reminder_email'))
    <input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email">
@else
    <input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" {{ $baby_registry->reminder_email ? 'checked' : false }}>
@endif
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" {{ $reminder_email ? 'checked' : '' }}>
Is there no value attribute ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
But I am not sure about what it is sending as there is no **value** attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" @if(old('reminder_email', $baby_registry->reminder_email))checked @endif >
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
@if(isset($reminder_email))
<input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" checked>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" value='1' {{ old('reminder_email', $baby_registry->reminder_email)? 'checked="checked"':null }}>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check boxes inputs are not present in the `$_POST` global if they were not checked.

So i'll suggest you try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reminder_email" id="reminder_email" {{ !$reminder_email ? "" : "checked" }} />
```